# df.apply return NaN in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I am trying to fill up a column in a dataframe with 1, 0 or -1 depending on some factors by doing it like this:

```
def set_order_signal(row):
    
    if (row.MACD > row.SIGNAL) and (df.iloc[i-1].MACD < df.iloc[i-1].SIGNAL):
        if (row.MACD < 0 and row.SIGNAL < 0) and (row.close > row['200EMA']): 
            return 1
            
    elif (row.MACD < row.SIGNAL) and (df.iloc[i-1].MACD > df.iloc[i-1].SIGNAL):
        if (row.MACD > 0 and row.SIGNAL > 0) and (row.close < row['200EMA']):
            return -1
    else:
        return 0
```

Sometimes it works but in other rows it returns "NaN". I can't find a reason or solution for this.

The dataframe I work with looks like this:

```
time    open    high    low close   tick_volume spread  real_volume EMA_LONG    EMA_SHORT   MACD    SIGNAL  HIST    200EMA  OrderSignal
0   2018-01-09 05:00:00 1.19726 1.19751 1.19675 1.19717 1773    1   0   1.197605    1.197152    -0.000453   -0.000453   0.000000e+00    1.197170    0.0
1   2018-01-09 06:00:00 1.19717 1.19724 1.19659 1.19681 1477    1   0   1.197538    1.197099    -0.000439   -0.000445   6.258599e-06    1.196989    0.0
2   2018-01-09 07:00:00 1.19681 1.19718 1.19642 1.19651 1622    1   0   1.197452    1.197008    -0.000444   -0.000445   5.327180e-07    1.196828    0.0
3   2018-01-09 08:00:00 1.19650 1.19650 1.19518 1.19560 3543    1   0   1.197298    1.196789    -0.000509   -0.000466   -4.237181e-05   1.196516    NaN
```

I'm trying to apply it to the df with this:

```
df['OrderSignal'] = df.apply(set_order_signal, axis=1)
```

Is it a format problem?

Thank you already!

Comment: What is *i* in your function?

Comment: I aaumed that 'i' is the index the apply function has in it when iterating through the df. So with 'df.iloc[i-1]' I want the previous row.

Comment: How would you do it? I can't find what i is but it also doesn't throw an error

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the index of the row that is sent to function, you need to use row.name, not i.

Try this and see what you get for your results. Can't tell if the logic is correct in all cases, but the four rows returns 0 each time

```
def set_order_signal(row):
    if (row.MACD > row.SIGNAL) and (df.iloc[row.name-1].MACD < df.iloc[row.name-1].SIGNAL):
        if (row.MACD < 0 and row.SIGNAL < 0) and (row.close > row['200EMA']): 
            return 1
            
    elif (row.MACD < row.SIGNAL) and (df.iloc[row.name-1].MACD > df.iloc[row.name-1].SIGNAL):
        if (row.MACD > 0 and row.SIGNAL > 0) and (row.close < row['200EMA']):
            return -1
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: Well at least I am now getting some '1's and the others are '0' or NaN. But still no '-1'. Is it maybe because of the format. Maybe the coloumn is in a format that can't return a '-1' and it replaces it with the NaN?

Comment: consider rewriting the conditions as one statement instead of nesting the ifs. it's possible it's evaluating the first and returns 1, but somehow can't move on in some cases and produces a Nan. if you post more data that you are certain contains all three cases we can look at the logic.

Comment: Hi and sorry for the late response. I have found the problem. It was indeed the "-1" that couldn't be written in the df. I have changed it now so that instead of "-1" it writes a "2" instead and it works. Still thank you very much for your time!

Comment: interesting. wouldn't have thought that'd be the issue, but glad you found a solution